# How to send POST request from localhost (http) to django (https)?

Tags: django, http, https, proxy, django-csrf

Send to proxy `/api` with all params (header/cookie/post) as [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)

[image: PrtScreen with request param (header/cookie/post)]

And get

[image: PrtScreen with response 403 Forbidden]

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs'),
    proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function returnIndexPageFn(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(fs.readFileSync('./public/app.html'));
    res.end();
    next();
}

browserSync.init({
    port: 88,
    server: {
        baseDir: 'public/',
        index: 'app.html',
        middleware: [
            {route: '/home', handle: returnIndexPageFn},
            proxy(['/api', '/media'], {
                target: 'https://security-site.com',
                logLevel: 'debug',
                changeOrigin: true,
                headers: {
                    Referer: 'https://security-site.com',
                },
            })
        ]
    }
});
```

I try another with angular 5, but have the same result(((

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://security-site.com/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "info"
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution:

*Need change header `Referal` to **https** protocol*

For [browser-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync)

**server.js**

```
...
    proxy(['/api', '/media'], {
        target: 'https://security-site.com',
        logLevel: 'debug',
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
            Referer: 'https://security-site.com',
        },
    })
...
```

For angular 5 (angular cli):
**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "https://security-site.com/",
        "headers": {
            "Referer": "https://security-site.com/"
        },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "info"
    }
}
```